# VLC Mozilla webplugin causes blank screen

Tags: vlc, mozilla, cefsharp

I have been tasked with testing a video streaming app built using cefsharp framework. The app uses flash player and works fine. However if VLC Mozilla plugin is installed the videos does not player instead there is a blank black screen in place of the video frame. Is there any solution for this solution other than uninstalling VLC and installing it back without the plugin.

Comment: Is it a `PPAPI` plugin or an older `NPAPI`?

Comment: What version are you using? Newer versions no longer support NPAPI so you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the VLC plugin by opening the `about:addons` page in Firefox and then set the options dropbox related to the plugin to "Never Activate".